# Regex class [.] doesn't match '(' ')' or '$'

Tags: java, android, regex, expression

I have a simple regex :

```
String expr = "#^" + STARTER + "[.]" + ENDER + "$#";
c = c.replaceAll(expr, STARTER + REPLACEMENT + ENDER);
```

Result :

A string which contains

```
STARTER an exemple ENDER
```

matches but :

```
STARTER an (exemple) ENDER
```

doesn't match.

Why are the characters `)`, `(` and `$` excluded from the `.` regex class?
How can I make it accept any character?

Comment: If STARTER and ENDER contain special symbols replace wouldn't work correctly.

Comment: What are the contents of `STARTER` and `ENDER`, exactly? I'm pretty sure that the regex you're constructing here can't match either of the example strings because none of them contain a literal dot which is the only thing that `[.]` would match. Also, Java regexes don't use delimiters like PHP, so the `#`s would also throw the engine off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `STARTER` and `ENDER` are supposed to be literal strings, not regexes themselves, and that your goal is to match a string that starts with `STARTER`, ends with `ENDER` and may contain anything (except newlines) in-between, you could use

```
String expr = "^" + Pattern.quote(STARTER) + ".*" + Pattern.quote(ENDER) + "$";
```

This means that there can be only one match per string.

So, if `STARTER == "Start"`, `ENDER == "End"` and `REPLACEMENT == "Replace"`, the `replaceAll()` call would do the following:

```
"Start foobar End"      --> "StartReplaceEnd"
"StartEnd"              --> "StartReplaceEnd"
" Start foobar End"     --> " Start foobar End"
"Start foo\nbar End"    --> "Start foo\nbar End"
"foo Start bar End baz" --> "foo Start bar End baz"
"Start End\nStart End"  --> "Start End\nStart End"
```

Since this doesn't make much sense, you might want to explain what your actual goal for this regex is.

Answer (score 2):

`.` (dot) isn't a regex class, it is a special symbol, which has its special meaning only outside `[]`.

Dot accept any char (except maybe `\n`) w/o `[]`.